# Lining up values in pretty print table view java

Tags: java, java-8, pretty-print

Is there a foolproof or simple way to line up values after printing them out in a "pretty table view" fashion?

My code for a test dataset is:

```
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, true, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(5000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(5000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, true, true));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(5000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(5000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(5000), Arrays.asList(false, true, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, true, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(false, false, false));
        map.put(10000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, true, false));
        map.put(100 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
        map.put(1000 + r.nextInt(50000), Arrays.asList(true, false, true));

        int counter = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Boolean>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + " \t");
            if (counter == 5) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                counter = 0;
                sb.setLength(0);
            }
            counter++;
        }
```

I am using a test data set because the real one is too much data and its easier to work in smaller batches, but the output looks exactly like:

```
30336 = [true, false, true]     2820 = [true, false, false]     17029 = [false, false, false]   10183 = [true, true, false]     14600 = [true, true, false]     9741 = [true, false, true]  
32717 = [true, true, false]     3664 = [true, true, false]  22610 = [true, false, true]     49618 = [true, true, false]     43476 = [true, false, true]     
4439 = [true, false, true]  1816 = [false, false, false]    57562 = [true, false, true]     23450 = [false, true, true]     21018 = [true, false, false]    
35291 = [false, false, false]   40923 = [true, false, false]    5342 = [true, true, false]  32353 = [false, false, false]   48098 = [true, true, false]     
41442 = [false, false, false]   39269 = [true, true, false]     11623 = [false, true, true]     45031 = [true, false, false]    23720 = [true, false, false]    
23209 = [false, false, false]   37419 = [false, true, true]     26798 = [true, false, true]     1454 = [false, true, true]  2544 = [true, false, false]     
12080 = [true, false, false]    26418 = [false, false, false]   24052 = [true, false, true]     50293 = [false, false, false]   25720 = [true, false, true]
```

The key Integer ranges are big, which is what gives me the idea that its not lining up properly, and the word "false" is longer than the word "true", so if certain entries' values are more falses than trues, then it would mess up the lining too. But is there a foolproof or simple way to fix this? I've tried doing the `sb.append(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + " \t");` with an `StringUtils.leftPad/rightPad` but the results are similar, its nearly in a straight line but its jagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it is inconsistent to mix `StringBuilder` with string concatenation like

```java
sb.append(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + " \t");
```

Instead, the `StringBuilder` should be used as intended, e.g.

```java
sb.append(entry.getKey()).append(" = ").append(entry.getValue()).append(" \t");
```

From there,. it is only a small step to break the call chain into individual statements and insert padding as necessary:

```java
final String columnSeparator = "|";
final int keyWidth = 6, valueWidth = "false, ".length() * 3;

int counter = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Boolean>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    int colStart = sb.length(), colEnd = colStart + keyWidth;
    sb.append((int)entry.getKey());
    while(sb.length() < colEnd) sb.insert(colStart, ' '); // right aligned
    sb.append(" = ");
    colEnd = sb.length() + valueWidth;
    sb.append(entry.getValue());
    while(sb.length() < colEnd) sb.append(' '); // left aligned
    if(counter == 5) {
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        sb.append(columnSeparator);
        counter++;
    }
}
if(counter != 0) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - columnSeparator.length());
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
System.out.append(sb);
```

producing an output like

```
 14339 = [false, false, false]|  4869 = [true, false, false] | 17669 = [true, false, false] |  3526 = [false, false, false]|  1864 = [false, true, true]  |  9224 = [false, true, true]  
 30152 = [true, true, false]  | 19273 = [false, false, false]| 49547 = [true, true, false]  |  5391 = [true, false, false] |  4943 = [false, false, false]| 39311 = [true, false, true]  
  7889 = [true, false, true]  | 31893 = [false, false, false]| 49174 = [true, true, false]  |  3094 = [true, false, true]  | 16854 = [true, false, true]  | 27094 = [true, false, false] 
 46234 = [true, true, false]  | 22751 = [true, false, false] | 58339 = [false, false, false]| 49700 = [true, false, true]  | 44901 = [true, false, false] | 49254 = [true, false, true]  
 24230 = [true, true, false]  | 45799 = [true, true, false]  | 39591 = [true, false, true]  | 17450 = [false, false, false]| 30893 = [true, false, true]  | 14189 = [true, false, true]  
 33583 = [false, true, true]  | 29365 = [false, false, false]|  5563 = [false, true, true]  | 17341 = [true, true, false]  |  5245 = [true, true, false]  | 18302 = [true, false, false] 
  4223 = [true, false, false]
```

You may change the `columnSeparator` to `" | "` to have more spacing or to something like `"  "` to only use spaces or to an empty string, as you like. You can also adapt `keyWidth` and `valueWidth` to the real life scenario.

---

Above solution uses `sb.insert` in a loop, which is only feasible when we know that the number of characters that have to be shifted is small (it’s an integer number) and the number of iterations will be small (here, we have either four or five digits, so it iterates at most two times).

When the divergence between the actual key lengths can be greater, you can eliminate the loop by inserting `String pad = " ".repeat(keyWidth);` before the `for` loop and replacing

```java
while(sb.length() < colEnd) sb.insert(colStart, ' ');
```

with

```java
if(sb.length() < colEnd) sb.insert(colStart, pad, 0, colEnd - sb.length());
```

When you also change the key type to something that could produce rather large strings, you may avoid `insert` altogether by replacing

```java
sb.append((int)entry.getKey());
while(sb.length() < colEnd) sb.insert(colStart, ' '); // right aligned
```

with

```java
String key = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());
if(key.length() < keyWidth) sb.append(pad, 0, keyWidth - key.length());
sb.append(key);
```

But this only pays off for objects that have to be appended via their `toString()` method anyway, not for `Integer` keys appended via `append(int)` without an intermediate string that has to be copied.

---

If you have fixed column width and want a simple solution, you can use

```java
int counter = 0;
for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Boolean>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf(++counter%5 != 0? "%6d = %-21s|": "%6d = %21s%n",
        entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
if(counter % 5 != 0) System.out.println();
```

Comment: Hmm, this is great. But I was also wondering, would using String.format() solve this issue where you can give it a fixed length? I'm trying to wrap my head around using String.format but I am getting confused with what arguments to put into the String.format()

Comment: Yes, when you have fixed lengths, you could use `String.format`, but mind that this is just a façade for [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html). When you are populating an already existing `StringBuilder`, it’s worth instantiating it directly with the target buffer. If you prefer simplicity over performance, just use `System.out.printf(…)` which is another façade to the formatter, now with `System.out` as its direct target. I added the code at the end of my answer. The disadvantage is that the format is parsed on each call

Comment: So the dilemma of me using StringBuilder, is because I have to use scenario.write. The purpose of this is to display it out onto a cucumber report using scenario.write and scenario.write only writes line by line which is why I wanted to do some sort of concatenation and then using scenario.write to go row by row after X amount of concatenations. But using System.out.printf may solve the issue in the console, im not sure how it will solve the issue in the cucumber report using scenario.write. That is why i wanted to store it into a StringBuilder and then using scenario.write to print it out

Comment: As said, then use `Formatter` directly: `int counter = 0; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); Formatter f = new Formatter(sb); for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Boolean>> entry : map.entrySet()) {  f.format(++counter != 5? "%6d = %-21s|": "%6d = %21s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); if(counter == 5) {  scenario.write(sb); sb.setLength(0); counter = 0; }  }  if(sb.length() != 0) scenario.write(sb);`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sb.append(entry.getKey() + "\t=\t" + entry.getValue() + " \t");
```

Comment: This works quite well actually, but is there a way to say, make the \t smaller? Because there seems to be a bit larger space than what I'd like before and after the =

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion the size of the tab depends on your text editor/terminal

Comment: Would there be a way to do this using String.Utils right/leftPad?